# Error, "Code will never be executed", with output stream

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with this code in Xcode:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream out;
    char c;
   out.open("call_data.txt");
   if (out.fail())
       cout << "failed." << endl; exit(1);
   cout << "Print something to a file :" << exit(1);//I get the error here
   cin >> c;
   out << c;
   out.close();
   return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me why I get this error? I can't figure it out. Am I maybe opening the output stream incorrectly? I feel like it has worked before like this.

Comment: Not sure why you are doing this `<< exit(1);` ?

Comment: I incorrectly copied it; it's supposed to be <<endl;

Comment: "Inspired by early line and character editors that broke a move or copy operation into two steps—between which the user could invoke a preparatory action such as navigation—Lawrence G. Tesler (Larry Tesler) proposed the names "cut" and "copy" for the first step and "paste" for the second step. Beginning in 1974, he and colleagues at Xerox Corporation Palo Alto Research Center (PARC) implemented several text editors that used cut/copy-and-paste commands to move/copy text."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sane formatting your code looks like this:

```
ofstream out;
char c;
out.open("call_data.txt");
if (out.fail())
   cout << "failed." << endl;
exit(1);
cout << "Print something to a file :" << endl; //exit(1) shouldn't be here either
cin >> c;
out << c;
out.close();
```

Call to `exit` will always happen, anything later cannot be reached. Use `{}` for multi-statement `if`s:

```
if (out.fail()) {
    cout << "failed." << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is probably because you forgot to use brackets with your if statement. Here is what it should look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream out;
    char c;
   out.open("call_data.txt");
   if (out.fail())
   {
       cout << "failed." << endl;
       exit(1);
   }
   cout << "Print something to a file :" << exit(1);//I get the error here
   cin >> c;
   out << c;
   out.close();
   return 0;
}
```